# mailto attribute does not work on mobile

Tags: android, html, email

My mailto attribute does not work in the default android browser  (before 4.0). It opens a new browser that cannot find the link.

```
<form enctype="text/plain" method="post" action="mailto:physio@info.de">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use a form in this way, you are trying to post to the server. So when you click on the submit button of this form, your browser is trying to post to the server at the address "mailto:physio@info.de", which is not a valid URL.

The correct use of a mailto link is with an anchor, this will give you the desired effect:

```
<a href="mailto:physio@info.de">email me</a>
```